# How to make Javascript Count Up timer work

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to implement a simple count up timer using Javascript and show the timer in the HTML page. This is my code:

```
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime()
{
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
}

function pad(val)
{
    var valString = val + "";
    if(valString.length < 2)
    {
        return "0" + valString;
    }
    else
    {
        return valString;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label id="minutes">00</label>
    <label id="colon">:</label>
    <label id="seconds">00</label>
```

But the timer is not working in the HTML. It stays at `00:00`

Comment: Try using `setInterval()`. You can learn about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: can you show the complete html page? I have copied the same code and it is working fine for me.
 <script type="text/javascript" src="yourfile.js"></script>

Comment: Yes the code works in the snippet, but for some reason it does not work on my end

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the script is at the bottom on the body tag

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted works exactly as you describe.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anpel13/ty8zgmde/3/), I just copy pasted it.

```
.
```

Comment: Yes the code works in the snippet, but for some reason it does not work on my end

Comment: Then some other part of your code must have an error. Can you please check your console?

Comment: yeah I had the script at the beginning of the body. Had to move it to the closing tag of the body

Comment: @efuzz Indeed, `getElementById` (or any other function that gets DOM nodes) will not work unless the nodes already exist. You can either move your script to the bottom of the `body` or wrap it in an `onload` function.

Answer (score 0):

The code you mentioned is working perfectly fine in the snippets.

Comment: Yes the code works in the snippet, but for some reason it does not work on my end